# SDL Application error: expected unqualified-id before ‘if’

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2, linux-mint

When I compile this SDL code I get this error:

```
SDL_DEV.cpp:60:2: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘if’


if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
  ^
SDL_DEV.cpp:64:2: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘else’
  else
  ^
Makefile:21: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

(I am compiling this with g++ in Linux mint with SDL 2.0.5 installed)

Here is the full source code

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>


const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{

    SDL_Window* window = NULL;


    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;


    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    }
    else
    {

        window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        if( window == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        }
        else
        {

            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( window );


            SDL_FillRect( screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB( screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );


            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );


            SDL_Delay( 2000 );
        }
    }


    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );


    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}   
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;


    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;


    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    }
    else
    {

        window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        if( window == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        }
        else
        {

            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( window );


            SDL_FillRect( screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB( screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );


            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );


            SDL_Delay( 2000 );
        }
    }


    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );


    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error, because I have compiled it before on a different machine. I would be very happy if someone could help me figure this problem out. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, you have exactly same code after `main` ends... Did you copy-paste `main` content by accident?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I guess I just didn't see the extra code when I copied it over from my windows platform.